# Any references for SSE/AVX instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, simd, avx

So far I've found pages that simply list the instructions and not what they do, and the Intel manuals which have a table of contents that tells me the names and tells me what they do 1000 pages later...so I'm looking for a smaller reference that has the instructions and a basic rundown of what they do, so I can find which ones I want to use and the read further on those specific ones in the Intel manual. Any suggestions?

P.S. I'm NOT asking about intrinsics for C. I'm asking about assembly language.

Comment: You're looking for this: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-intrinsics-guide

Comment: No, I'm not using C. I'm asking about the actual instructions for assembly programming. Not intrinsics.

Comment: Yes, the guide covers the asm instructions too (up to a point) - did you try it ?

Comment: I looked at it, but I was asking if anyone knew of any "quick references" or something because I want to be able to look down a table, find an instruction to "add so and so registers and do so and so" and then read on about the instruction in the manual, or in the intrinsic guide

Comment: That's exactly what the intrinsics guide does, except that if you need full details for a given instruction once you've found it then you're back to the Intel PDF manuals - there isn't really any way around that though - it's a ton of information, but using good tools to access it will help.

Comment: OK, I'll take a closer look at that intrinsic guide. Thank you